# Add/Remove classes using media queries

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries

**My general question is how can one conditionally add or remove classes or ids to a particular class using css media queries alone? In the sample code below, for example, how could I add "Class_B" to all of the div's with "Class_A" when `@media all and (max-width: 1000px) and (min-width: 700px)`?**

```
<div class="Class_A"><div>
```

---

My specific case: I'm using Twitter Bootstrap v3.2.0.  I have a header with a series of buttons in it like so:

```
<button class="btn navbar-btn">FooA</button>
<button class="btn navbar-btn">FooB</button>
<button class="btn navbar-btn">FooC</button>
```

**When the screen jumps from medium (md) to small(sm), I would like to add the class "btn-sm" to all of those elements. How can I do that most efficiently/elegantly?** (I would prefer not to use JS or add any additional libraries if that's possible)

I realize I could add an arbitrary class to all those buttons like "btn-sm-duplicate" and only define it when the browser reaches a certain specification like the code below. However, it seems ugly to create a duplicate class when it's really not nec... Can you suggest something?

```
@media all and (max-width: 1000px) and (min-width: 700px) {
       btn-sm-duplicate{

::Copy/Paste all the attributes of btn-sm from bootstrap::

       }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it's ugly?

Comment: @DavidG - I think it's ugly because of the repetition of the btn-sm css. I'm hoping to avoid creating a btn-sm-duplicate class at all.

Comment: What's the point of adding another class, just update the css rules for the same class within the media query. The whole point of the media query is to allow you to change the rules based on width. It seems like you are over thinking it

Comment: @Haungism Actually if you have something like `.column-50` and then set width to 100%  that's not so right so changing class name is a good way to get around it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot do this with CSS alone. One approach would be to take advantage of `extend` in a CSS pre-processor like LESS.

LESS example:

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
    btn-sm-duplicate{
        &:extend(.btn-sm);
    }
}
```

Another approach would be to use Javascript to add the class based on screen size. A library like [Modernizr.mq](http://modernizr.com/docs/#mq) makes this pretty easy.

Comment: This is now allowed in SCSS. Trying to extend an existing class from within a media query will yield the following error:  `Error: You may not @extend an outer selector from within @media. You may only @extend selectors within the same directive.`